# 400 Bad Request error attempting to insert values into Google BigQuery

Tags: python-3.x, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I'm new at using Google Cloud Composer (Apache Airflow) and I'm trying to create a DAG that runs a script to INSERT some values to a BigQuery table (in a different project).
DAGS directory is set up at gcs/dags/.
BQ table is already created with correct fields and data types.

Whenever it's attempting to do the `insert_to_bq` task, it always returns an error:
`google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Braced constructors are not supported`

Here's the code that I'm running:

```
...
SQL_INSERT = f"INSERT {BQ_TABLE_ID} ({BQ_INSERT_COLS}) VALUES('{VAR_1}', TIMESTAMP({{ts}}), '{VAR_3}')"

# DAG
with models.DAG(
    'dag_name',
    default_args = DEFAULT_ARGS,
    schedule_interval = '@once'
) as dag:
    ...
    insert_to_bq = BigQueryOperator(
        task_id = "insert_to_bq_task",
        write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND',
        create_disposition = 'CREATE_NEVER',
        sql = SQL_INSERT,
        use_legacy_sql = False,
        dag = dag
    ...
```

I've already tried using another operator but produces the same error:

```
...
insert_to_bq = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id = "insert_to_bq_task"
    configuration = {
        "query" : {
            "query" : SQL_INSERT,
            "useLegacySql" : False,
            "destinationTable" : {
                "projectId" : "project-id",
                "datasetId" : "dataset_id",
                "tableId" : "table_id"
            },
            "writeDisposition" : "WRITE_APPEND",
        }
    },
    location = "my_location"
)
```

I've already searched for the error code it's giving but cannot find any informative descriptions on why it's happening.
Currently stuck at this and I deeply appreciate on any tips, advice, or anything that can help me resolve this issue. Let me know if there is anything else that I need to provide to further understand and troubleshoot the issue.

---

**UPDATE**:

Resolved by adding a parameter called `params` in BigQueryOperator which consists of a dictionary for the values you want to dynamically put into variables.

```
SQL_INSERT = f'''
INSERT {{ params.table_id }} {{ params.columns }}
VALUES('{{ params.var_string }}', TIMESTAMP({{ params.timestamp }}))
'''
...
insert_to_bq = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id="insert_to_bq_task",
    write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND',
    create_disposition='CREATE_NEVER',
    sql=SQL_INSERT,
    use_legacy_sql=False,
    params={
        'table_id':'bq_table_id',
        'columns':'bq_columns',
        'var_string':'string_value',
        'timestamp':datetime.now(),
    }
)
...
```

Comment: If you test the same code with the destination table in the same project, have you the same error ?

Comment: @MazlumTosun hi, thanks for reaching out. Unfortunately yes, it returns the same error.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is not due to your use of Operators `BigQueryOperator` or `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`, but to the way you build your SQL query.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74931417/problems-querying-with-python-to-bigquery-python-string-format) that indicate the same kind of error when executing an `SQL` query with `BigQuery`.

Please try to execute your code with a simple query without dynamic parameters then find the good way to add these parameter later.

Comment: Great advice @MazlumTosun ! I removed the dynamic parameters in `SQL_INSERT` and tried to run it, and it worked!

I also found out that to have dynamic parameters in the `BigQueryOperator`, I needed to pass an argument of `params` which consists of a dictionary of key-value pairs.